# What addresses do we get after we call SymGetLineFromAddr64() and SymGetSymFromAddr64() WinAPI functions?

Tags: c++, winapi

```
[IMAGEHLP_SYMBOL64][1] *pSym = NULL;
[IMAGEHLP_LINE64][2] Line;
STACKFRAME64 s; 
int d = 0;

//In my code I obtain the return address from the stack frame of function foo() which was called from function bar() and assign it to s.AddrPC.Offset. Now I call - 

SymGetLineFromAddr64(this->m_hProcess, s.AddrPC.Offset, &(d), &Line) 

SymGetSymFromAddr64(this->m_hProcess, s.AddrPC.Offset, &(d), pSym))

//We pass the current process HANDLE
//pSym->Name = bar
```

What addresses do these contain?

```
Line.Address;

pSym->Address;
```

**Found! pSym->Address gives the virtual address for the function name**

I have been trying to figure this out for a long time. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of editing your question to contain the answer, write an actual answer below, and accept that.

Comment: @jalf: It's not a complete answer and I don't want to accept my own answer. If I find out the answer I would delete the question.

Comment: Judging by the number of views I don't think anyone is interested in the question :) But I understand your viewpoint and will not delete the question. I want to give someone else a chance to answer the question and get points instead of doing so myself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you were looking for:

From [help page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) , structure of `IMAGEHLP_SYMBOL64` is the below:

```
typedef struct _IMAGEHLP_SYMBOL64 {
  DWORD   SizeOfStruct;
  DWORD64 Address;
  DWORD   Size;
  DWORD   Flags;
  DWORD   MaxNameLength;
  TCHAR   Name[1];
} IMAGEHLP_SYMBOL64, *PIMAGEHLP_SYMBOL64;
```

**`Address`** being the address of ***the symbol***.

In your case, `pSym->Address` appears to be the ***virtual address for the function name***.

This question is also very similar to [StackWalk64 on Windows - Get symbol name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705650/stackwalk64-on-windows-get-symbol-name) .