# Windows C++ stack trace from a running app

Tags: visual-c++

All,

I saw an app, an SVN Visual Studio plugin, that displayed a beautiful readable stack trace, when it crashed.

I would love to add that to my application. 
How do I provide that? No emailing of the information, just a visual display is enough.

Answer (score 28):

The core of the necessary code is `StackWalk64`. To get much from that, you'll also want/need to get symbol names with `SymGetSymFromAddr64` (which requires `SymLoadModule64`) and (probably) `SymGetLineFromAddr64` and `GetThreadContext`. If the target was written in C++, you'll probably also want to use `UnDecorateSymbolName`. Along with those you'll need a few ancillaries like `SymInitialize`, `SymCleanup`, and probably `SymSetOptions`.

Here's a fairly minimal demo. The stack dump it produces is more utilitarian than beautiful, but presumably with the basics of doing the stack trace, you can display the results as you see fit:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winnt.h>

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <Psapi.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iterator>

#pragma comment(lib, "psapi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dbghelp.lib")

// Some versions of imagehlp.dll lack the proper packing directives themselves
// so we need to do it.
#pragma pack( push, before_imagehlp, 8 )
#include <imagehlp.h>
#pragma pack( pop, before_imagehlp )

struct module_data {
    std::string image_name;
    std::string module_name;
    void *base_address;
    DWORD load_size;
};
typedef std::vector<module_data> ModuleList;

HANDLE thread_ready;

bool show_stack(std::ostream &, HANDLE hThread, CONTEXT& c);
DWORD __stdcall TargetThread( void *arg );
void ThreadFunc1();
void ThreadFunc2();
DWORD Filter( EXCEPTION_POINTERS *ep );
void *load_modules_symbols( HANDLE hProcess, DWORD pid );

int main( void ) {
    DWORD thread_id;

    thread_ready = CreateEvent( NULL, false, false, NULL );

    HANDLE thread = CreateThread( NULL, 0, TargetThread, NULL, 0, &thread_id );

    WaitForSingleObject( thread_ready, INFINITE );
    CloseHandle(thread_ready);
    return 0;
}

// if you use C++ exception handling: install a translator function
// with set_se_translator(). In the context of that function (but *not*
// afterwards), you can either do your stack dump, or save the CONTEXT
// record as a local copy. Note that you must do the stack dump at the
// earliest opportunity, to avoid the interesting stack-frames being gone
// by the time you do the dump.
DWORD Filter(EXCEPTION_POINTERS *ep) {
    HANDLE thread;

    DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), GetCurrentThread(),
        GetCurrentProcess(), &thread, 0, false, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS);
    std::cout << "Walking stack.";
    show_stack(std::cout, thread, *(ep->ContextRecord));
    std::cout << "\nEnd of stack walk.\n";
    CloseHandle(thread);

    return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
}

void ThreadFunc2() {
    __try { DebugBreak(); }
    __except (Filter(GetExceptionInformation())) {  }
    SetEvent(thread_ready);
}

void ThreadFunc1(void (*f)()) {
    f();
}

// We'll do a few levels of calls from our thread function so 
//     there's something on the stack to walk...
//
DWORD __stdcall TargetThread(void *) {
    ThreadFunc1(ThreadFunc2);
    return 0;
}

class SymHandler { 
    HANDLE p;
public:
    SymHandler(HANDLE process, char const *path=NULL, bool intrude = false) : p(process) { 
        if (!SymInitialize(p, path, intrude)) 
            throw(std::logic_error("Unable to initialize symbol handler"));
    }
    ~SymHandler() { SymCleanup(p); }
};

#ifdef _M_X64
STACKFRAME64 init_stack_frame(CONTEXT c) {
    STACKFRAME64 s;
    s.AddrPC.Offset = c.Rip;
    s.AddrPC.Mode = AddrModeFlat;
    s.AddrStack.Offset = c.Rsp;
    s.AddrStack.Mode = AddrModeFlat;    
    s.AddrFrame.Offset = c.Rbp;
    s.AddrFrame.Mode = AddrModeFlat;
    return s;
}
#else
STACKFRAME64 init_stack_frame(CONTEXT c) {
    STACKFRAME64 s;
    s.AddrPC.Offset = c.Eip;
    s.AddrPC.Mode = AddrModeFlat;
    s.AddrStack.Offset = c.Esp;
    s.AddrStack.Mode = AddrModeFlat;    
    s.AddrFrame.Offset = c.Ebp;
    s.AddrFrame.Mode = AddrModeFlat;
    return s;
}
#endif

void sym_options(DWORD add, DWORD remove=0) {
    DWORD symOptions = SymGetOptions();
    symOptions |= add;
    symOptions &= ~remove;
    SymSetOptions(symOptions);
}

class symbol { 
    typedef IMAGEHLP_SYMBOL64 sym_type;
    sym_type *sym;
    static const int max_name_len = 1024;
public:
    symbol(HANDLE process, DWORD64 address) : sym((sym_type *)::operator new(sizeof(*sym) + max_name_len)) {
        memset(sym, '\0', sizeof(*sym) + max_name_len);
        sym->SizeOfStruct = sizeof(*sym);
        sym->MaxNameLength = max_name_len;
        DWORD64 displacement;

        if (!SymGetSymFromAddr64(process, address, &displacement, sym))
            throw(std::logic_error("Bad symbol"));
    }

    std::string name() { return std::string(sym->Name); }
    std::string undecorated_name() { 
        std::vector<char> und_name(max_name_len);
        UnDecorateSymbolName(sym->Name, &und_name[0], max_name_len, UNDNAME_COMPLETE);
        return std::string(&und_name[0], strlen(&und_name[0]));
    }
};

bool show_stack(std::ostream &os, HANDLE hThread, CONTEXT& c) {
    HANDLE process = GetCurrentProcess();
    int frame_number=0;
    DWORD offset_from_symbol=0;
    IMAGEHLP_LINE64 line = {0};

    SymHandler handler(process);

    sym_options(SYMOPT_LOAD_LINES | SYMOPT_UNDNAME);

    void *base = load_modules_symbols(process, GetCurrentProcessId());

    STACKFRAME64 s = init_stack_frame(c);

    line.SizeOfStruct = sizeof line;

    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *h = ImageNtHeader(base);
    DWORD image_type = h->FileHeader.Machine;

    do {
        if (!StackWalk64(image_type, process, hThread, &s, &c, NULL, SymFunctionTableAccess64, SymGetModuleBase64, NULL))
            return false;

        os << std::setw(3) << "\n" << frame_number << "\t";
        if ( s.AddrPC.Offset != 0 ) {
            std::cout << symbol(process, s.AddrPC.Offset).undecorated_name();

            if (SymGetLineFromAddr64( process, s.AddrPC.Offset, &offset_from_symbol, &line ) ) 
                    os << "\t" << line.FileName << "(" << line.LineNumber << ")";
        }
        else
            os << "(No Symbols: PC == 0)";
        ++frame_number;
    } while (s.AddrReturn.Offset != 0);
    return true;
}

class get_mod_info {
    HANDLE process;
    static const int buffer_length = 4096;
public:
    get_mod_info(HANDLE h) : process(h) {}

    module_data operator()(HMODULE module) { 
        module_data ret;
        char temp[buffer_length];
        MODULEINFO mi;

        GetModuleInformation(process, module, &mi, sizeof(mi));
        ret.base_address = mi.lpBaseOfDll;
        ret.load_size = mi.SizeOfImage;

        GetModuleFileNameEx(process, module, temp, sizeof(temp));
        ret.image_name = temp;
        GetModuleBaseName(process, module, temp, sizeof(temp));
        ret.module_name = temp;
        std::vector<char> img(ret.image_name.begin(), ret.image_name.end());
        std::vector<char> mod(ret.module_name.begin(), ret.module_name.end());
        SymLoadModule64(process, 0, &img[0], &mod[0], (DWORD64)ret.base_address, ret.load_size);
        return ret;
    }
};

void *load_modules_symbols(HANDLE process, DWORD pid) {
    ModuleList modules;

    DWORD cbNeeded;
    std::vector<HMODULE> module_handles(1);

    EnumProcessModules(process, &module_handles[0], module_handles.size() * sizeof(HMODULE), &cbNeeded);
    module_handles.resize(cbNeeded/sizeof(HMODULE));
    EnumProcessModules(process, &module_handles[0], module_handles.size() * sizeof(HMODULE), &cbNeeded);

    std::transform(module_handles.begin(), module_handles.end(), std::back_inserter(modules), get_mod_info(process));
    return modules[0].base_address;
}
```

Comment: I tried this code and it worked on my development laptop, but when my colleagues tried to run it, they don't get any of the stack trace information.  Do they need to install some .dll's or other files?

Comment: Hm...doesn't really need extra DLLs, but the executable needs to have debug information for it to do much.

Comment: I have debug information naturally.  On my development laptop, it works inside or outside VS++.  But on every laptop I've tried that does not have VS++ installed, I get no stack trace. Have you tried your code on computers that don't have VS++?

Comment: @TimCooper: Yes, quite a few--but it's been quite a while, so while I don't recall installing extra "stuff" to make it work, that could be just a result of my forgetfulness.

Comment: After some painstaking "message window" debugging, I learnt it's failing in SymGetSymFromAddr64() - this returns FALSE.  But when I walk the stack, this always returns FALSE _or_ it returns garbage that doesn't make sense (random unrelated method names). To reiterate, it's a debug mode .exe that produces a perfect symbolic stack trace on my development machine.

Comment: I finally solved my problem:  firstly, my clients need to have my .pdb file, and secondly their processes need to find my .pdb file through the search path provided as the 2nd parameter of "SymInitialize()".

Comment: This works great! (I used Tim's version of it, below.)  Jerry and @TimCooper, are you willing to license this code under a more permissive license (such as MIT) than was the default at the time this code was posted (apparently CC-By-SA, which is GPL-like)?

Comment: @MarkR: I'm fine with your using it under your choice of the Boost license or the MIT license.

Comment: @MarkR Sure, go ahead.

Answer (score 27):

I modified Jerry Coffin's code as you see below. Modifications:

A. I was always missing the most important frame of all: the line that actually triggered the exception. Turns out this was because the "do" loop was moving to the next frame at the top instead of at the bottom.

B. I removed the threading stuff.

C. I simplified a few bits.

You should cut the "WinMain()" function at the bottom and instead put the __try .. __except stuff in your own 'main/WinMain' function. Also replace 'YourMessage' with your own function to display a message box or email it or whatever.

The symbolic information is stored inside a .pdb file, not the .exe.  You need to give your users your .pdb file, and you need to ensure that their process can find it. See the  string inside the code below - replace this with a folder that will work on the users' machine, or NULL - NULL means it will search in the process's current working directory.  The .pdb file must have the exact same name on the users' computer as it had when you ran your compiler - to configure this to something different, see "Properties > Linker > Debugging > Generate Program Database File".

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <Psapi.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>


// Thanks, Jerry Coffin.

#pragma comment(lib, "psapi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dbghelp.lib")

// Some versions of imagehlp.dll lack the proper packing directives themselves
// so we need to do it.
#pragma pack( push, before_imagehlp, 8 )
#include <imagehlp.h>
#pragma pack( pop, before_imagehlp )

struct module_data {
    std::string image_name;
    std::string module_name;
    void *base_address;
    DWORD load_size;
};


DWORD DumpStackTrace( EXCEPTION_POINTERS *ep );
extern void YourMessage(const char* title, const char *fmt, ...);// Replace this with your own function




class symbol { 
    typedef IMAGEHLP_SYMBOL64 sym_type;
    sym_type *sym;
    static const int max_name_len = 1024;

public:
    symbol(HANDLE process, DWORD64 address) : sym((sym_type *)::operator new(sizeof(*sym) + max_name_len)) {
        memset(sym, '\0', sizeof(*sym) + max_name_len);
        sym->SizeOfStruct = sizeof(*sym);
        sym->MaxNameLength = max_name_len;
        DWORD64 displacement;

        SymGetSymFromAddr64(process, address, &displacement, sym);
    }

    std::string name() { return std::string(sym->Name); }
    std::string undecorated_name() { 
        if (*sym->Name == '\0')
            return "<couldn't map PC to fn name>";
        std::vector<char> und_name(max_name_len);
        UnDecorateSymbolName(sym->Name, &und_name[0], max_name_len, UNDNAME_COMPLETE);
        return std::string(&und_name[0], strlen(&und_name[0]));
    }
};


class get_mod_info {
    HANDLE process;
    static const int buffer_length = 4096;
public:
    get_mod_info(HANDLE h) : process(h) {}

    module_data operator()(HMODULE module) { 
        module_data ret;
        char temp[buffer_length];
        MODULEINFO mi;

        GetModuleInformation(process, module, &mi, sizeof(mi));
        ret.base_address = mi.lpBaseOfDll;
        ret.load_size = mi.SizeOfImage;

        GetModuleFileNameEx(process, module, temp, sizeof(temp));
        ret.image_name = temp;
        GetModuleBaseName(process, module, temp, sizeof(temp));
        ret.module_name = temp;
        std::vector<char> img(ret.image_name.begin(), ret.image_name.end());
        std::vector<char> mod(ret.module_name.begin(), ret.module_name.end());
        SymLoadModule64(process, 0, &img[0], &mod[0], (DWORD64)ret.base_address, ret.load_size);
        return ret;
    }
};


// if you use C++ exception handling: install a translator function
// with set_se_translator(). In the context of that function (but *not*
// afterwards), you can either do your stack dump, or save the CONTEXT
// record as a local copy. Note that you must do the stack dump at the
// earliest opportunity, to avoid the interesting stack-frames being gone
// by the time you do the dump.
DWORD DumpStackTrace(EXCEPTION_POINTERS *ep) 
{
    HANDLE process = GetCurrentProcess();
    HANDLE hThread = GetCurrentThread();
    int frame_number=0;
    DWORD offset_from_symbol=0;
    IMAGEHLP_LINE64 line = {0};
    std::vector<module_data> modules;
    DWORD cbNeeded;
    std::vector<HMODULE> module_handles(1);

    // Load the symbols:
    // WARNING: You'll need to replace <pdb-search-path> with either NULL
    // or some folder where your clients will be able to find the .pdb file.
    if (!SymInitialize(process, <pdb-search-path>, false)) 
        throw(std::logic_error("Unable to initialize symbol handler"));
    DWORD symOptions = SymGetOptions();
    symOptions |= SYMOPT_LOAD_LINES | SYMOPT_UNDNAME;
    SymSetOptions(symOptions);
    EnumProcessModules(process, &module_handles[0], module_handles.size() * sizeof(HMODULE), &cbNeeded);
    module_handles.resize(cbNeeded/sizeof(HMODULE));
    EnumProcessModules(process, &module_handles[0], module_handles.size() * sizeof(HMODULE), &cbNeeded);
    std::transform(module_handles.begin(), module_handles.end(), std::back_inserter(modules), get_mod_info(process));
    void *base = modules[0].base_address;

    // Setup stuff:
    CONTEXT* context = ep->ContextRecord;
#ifdef _M_X64
    STACKFRAME64 frame;
    frame.AddrPC.Offset = context->Rip;
    frame.AddrPC.Mode = AddrModeFlat;
    frame.AddrStack.Offset = context->Rsp;
    frame.AddrStack.Mode = AddrModeFlat;    
    frame.AddrFrame.Offset = context->Rbp;
    frame.AddrFrame.Mode = AddrModeFlat;
#else
    STACKFRAME64 frame;
    frame.AddrPC.Offset = context->Eip;
    frame.AddrPC.Mode = AddrModeFlat;
    frame.AddrStack.Offset = context->Esp;
    frame.AddrStack.Mode = AddrModeFlat;    
    frame.AddrFrame.Offset = context->Ebp;
    frame.AddrFrame.Mode = AddrModeFlat;
#endif
    line.SizeOfStruct = sizeof line;
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *h = ImageNtHeader(base);
    DWORD image_type = h->FileHeader.Machine;
    int n = 0;

    // Build the string:
    std::ostringstream builder;
    do {
        if ( frame.AddrPC.Offset != 0 ) {
            std::string fnName = symbol(process, frame.AddrPC.Offset).undecorated_name();
            builder << fnName;
            if (SymGetLineFromAddr64( process, frame.AddrPC.Offset, &offset_from_symbol, &line)) 
                builder << "  " /*<< line.FileName*/ << "(" << line.LineNumber << ")\n";
            else builder << "\n";
            if (fnName == "main")
                break;
            if (fnName == "RaiseException") {
                // This is what we get when compiled in Release mode:
                YourMessage("Crash", "Your program has crashed.\n\n");
                return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
            }
        }
        else
            builder << "(No Symbols: PC == 0)";
        if (!StackWalk64(image_type, process, hThread, &frame, context, NULL, 
                            SymFunctionTableAccess64, SymGetModuleBase64, NULL))
            break;
        if (++n > 10)
            break;
    } while (frame.AddrReturn.Offset != 0);
    //return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
    SymCleanup(process);

    // Display the string:
    YourMessage("Stack Trace", "Your program has crashed. Send a screenshot of this message to:\n"
            "you@initech.com\n\n%s", builder.str().c_str());
    return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
}


int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE _hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
        LPSTR args, int nCmdShow)
{
    __try { 
        // <Your code goes here>
        int f = 0;
        f = 7 / f;   // Trigger a divide-by-zero exception
        return 0;
    } __except (DumpStackTrace(GetExceptionInformation())) {  
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This was the only piece of code I found that could get me a stack trace after about 7 hours of printfing.  It deserves more points than I can give you.

Comment: @Tim Kind of basic question, but how can hook your code to my application so that it catches uncaught exceptions (divide by 0 for example)

Comment: The 'WinMain' provided above already gives you a divide-by-zero error, which is then caught, as a test of the framework.

Comment: Why does it bail when the stack trace exceeds 10?

Comment: Is there a simpler way to do this? On Mac/Linux, printing the stack trace can be done in under 10 lines of code. What's the minimum code to have a method that prints the stack trace when called? Assume I don't need any test code that calls it.

Answer (score 2):

OR use stackwalker from here...http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11132/Walking-the-callstack

use file stackwalker.cpp and stackwalker.h in your project

Minimal code:

```
#include "StackWalker.h"

class StackWalker2: public StackWalker
{
    public:
 string output;
  void OnOutput(LPCSTR szText)
  {
    output+=szText; // this will collect stack info in output string

  }

};

 StackWalker2 sw;
sw.ShowCallstack();
cout << sw.output;
```

You need to generate some debugging info to see function names and line numbers
Use proper flag in case of Microsoft VIsual C++
You may need to put .pdb file as well where your exe is.

Answer (score 1):

As of C++23 there's `std::stacktrace`. Before that or if your compiler doesn't support it yet there are a number of good C++ stacktrace libraries, including backwardcpp, boost stacktrace, and [cpptrace](https://github.com/jeremy-rifkin/cpptrace).

Comment: Thank you for this, but on Windows 11, it does nothing, no output.  I am using `std::stacktrace().current();`.  Maybe a fault on my part?

Comment: @Sabuncu The library reports to work on windows, it would be good to open an issue with more details if you are able.