# Does Stackwalk64 work on 64-bit Windows?

Tags: c++, winapi

Does Stackwalk64 work on Windows Server 2012 and 2008R2? I can't get this code to work. Anyone else here have it working? I use it to generate a stack trace for another thread.

I'm using:

```
myframe.AddrPC.Mode = AddrModeFlat;
myframe.AddrFrame.Mode = AddrModeFlat;
myframe.AddrStack.Mode = AddrModeFlat;
myframe.AddrPC.Offset = context.Rip;
myframe.AddrFrame.Offset = context.Rbp;
myframe.AddrStack.Offset = context.Rsp;             

while(pStackWalk64(IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64, GetCurrentProcess(), handleforanotherthread,&myframe,
    &context, NULL, funcTableAccess, SymGetModuleBase64, NULL))
{
    if(myframe.AddrPC.Offset == myframe.AddrReturn.Offset)
        break;
}
```

It fails and the address returned is not valid.

Comment: ..... nothing concrete to use here

Comment: How does it fail? Generally, if you are having a problem, it's yours not the libraries.

Comment: Yes. [This code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6207030/179910) has been tested on the 64-bit versions of XP, Vista and Windows 7.

Comment: fails by not fulling walking the stack and just stops after 2 frames

Comment: @JerryCoffin this piece of code works. but i try to understand why is different b/n I386 and AMD64. now in x64 i have to do SymLoadModule64 for all the modules but in x86 I dont do that.

Comment: @user1705409: Unless I'm rather mistaken, you're *supposed* to do it either way. Not exactly sure why you're getting away without doing it on x86, but it sounds to me like it's mostly "working" by accident.

Comment: @ no the same code actually works in x64 on 2003 as well.

Comment: @JerryCoffin also i try using this as base https://code.google.com/p/slimtune/

Answer (score 6):

Here is our version of this code.  The original came from an MSJ article but it has been heavily modified.

```
bool MSJExceptionHandler::ImagehlpStackWalk( PCONTEXT pCtx )
{
    bool result = false;
//  PCONTEXT pContext = pEP->ContextRecord;
    if( m_Levels == 0 ) {
        dbbTrace::OutputWithoutTimestamp( "\nCall stack:\n" );
        dbbTrace::OutputWithoutTimestamp( "Address   Frame\n" );
    }

    // Could use SymSetOptions here to add the SYMOPT_DEFERRED_LOADS flag

    STACKFRAME64 sf;
    bool first = true;
    FIXED_ARRAY( buf, char, 300 );
    size_t buflen = sizeof(buf);
    // Indexes into MSJExceptionHandler data when m_Levels > 0
    int i_line = 0; // Into char * m_Lines[]
    int i_buf = 0;  // into char m_Buffer[]

    memset( &sf, 0, sizeof(sf) );

    // Initialize the STACKFRAME structure for the first call.  This is only
    // necessary for Intel CPUs, and isn't mentioned in the documentation.

    DWORD64 pFrame = 0;
    DWORD64 pPrevFrame = 0;
    sf.AddrPC.Mode         = AddrModeFlat;
    sf.AddrStack.Mode      = AddrModeFlat;
    sf.AddrFrame.Mode      = AddrModeFlat;
#ifdef _M_IX86  // Intel Only!
    sf.AddrPC.Offset       = pCtx->Eip;
    sf.AddrStack.Offset    = pCtx->Esp;
    sf.AddrFrame.Offset    = pCtx->Ebp;
#endif
#ifdef _M_X64  // Intel Only!
    sf.AddrPC.Offset       = pCtx->Rip;
    sf.AddrStack.Offset    = pCtx->Rsp;
    sf.AddrFrame.Offset    = pCtx->Rbp;
#endif
#ifdef _M_IA64
    // Itanium
    DWORD64 pFrame, pPrevFrame;
#pragma message("fix me")
    sf.AddrPC.Offset       = 0;
    sf.AddrStack.Offset    = 0;
    sf.AddrFrame.Offset    = 0;
#endif

#ifdef _M_IX86
    DWORD MachineType = IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386;
#endif
#ifdef _M_X64
    DWORD MachineType = IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64;
#endif
#ifdef _M_IA64
    DWORD MachineType = IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_IA64;
#endif

    while ( 1 )
    {
        SetLastError( 0 );
        if ( ! StackWalk64( MachineType,
                            m_hProcess,
                            GetCurrentThread(),
                            &sf,
                            pCtx,
                            0,
                            SymFunctionTableAccess64,
                            SymGetModuleBase64,
                            0 ) )
            break;

        pFrame = sf.AddrFrame.Offset;
        if ( 0 == pFrame ) // Basic sanity check to make sure
            break;                      // the frame is OK.  Bail if not.

//        dbbTrace::OutputWithoutTimestamp( "%08X  %08X  ", sf.AddrPC.Offset, pFrame );

        if( ! first ) {
            if( pFrame <= pPrevFrame ) {
                // Sanity check
                break;
            }
            if( (pFrame - pPrevFrame) > 10000000 ) {
                // Sanity check
                break;
            }
        }
        if( (pFrame % sizeof(void *)) != 0 ) {
            // Sanity check
            break;
        }

        pPrevFrame = pFrame;
        first = false;

        // IMAGEHLP is wacky, and requires you to pass in a pointer to an
        // IMAGEHLP_SYMBOL structure.  The problem is that this structure is
        // variable length.  That is, you determine how big the structure is
        // at runtime.  This means that you can't use sizeof(struct).
        // So...make a buffer that's big enough, and make a pointer
        // to the buffer.  We also need to initialize not one, but TWO
        // members of the structure before it can be used.

        enum { emMaxNameLength = 512 };
        // Use union to ensure proper alignment
        union {
            SYMBOL_INFO symb;
            BYTE symbolBuffer[ sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO) + emMaxNameLength ];
        } u;
        PSYMBOL_INFO pSymbol = & u.symb;
        pSymbol->SizeOfStruct = sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO);
        pSymbol->MaxNameLen = emMaxNameLength;

        PDWORD64 symDisplacement = 0;  // Displacement of the input address,
                                    // relative to the start of the symbol

        DWORD lineDisplacement = 0;
        IMAGEHLP_LINE64  line;
        line.SizeOfStruct = sizeof(line);
        line.LineNumber = 0;
        BOOL bLine = FALSE;

        bLine = SymGetLineFromAddr64( m_hProcess, sf.AddrPC.Offset,
            & lineDisplacement, & line );
        if ( SymFromAddr(m_hProcess, sf.AddrPC.Offset,
                                symDisplacement, pSymbol) )
        {
            if( bLine ) {
                _snprintf( buf, buflen,
                    ADDR_FORMAT "  " ADDR_FORMAT "   %s() line %d\n",
                    sf.AddrPC.Offset, pFrame,
                    pSymbol->Name, line.LineNumber );
            } else {
                _snprintf( buf, buflen,
                    ADDR_FORMAT "  " ADDR_FORMAT "  %s() + %X\n",
                    sf.AddrPC.Offset, pFrame,
                    pSymbol->Name, symDisplacement );
            }

        }
        else    // No symbol found.  Print out the logical address instead.
        {
            DWORD err = GetLastError();
            FIXED_ARRAY( szModule , TCHAR, MAX_PATH );
            szModule[0] = '\0';
            DWORD section = 0, offset = 0;

            GetLogicalAddress(  (PVOID)sf.AddrPC.Offset,
                                szModule, sizeof(szModule), section, offset );

            _snprintf( buf, buflen,
                ADDR_FORMAT "  " ADDR_FORMAT "  %04X:%08X %s (err = %d)\n",
                sf.AddrPC.Offset, pFrame,
                section, offset, szModule, err );
            result = true;
        }

        if( m_Levels == 0 ) {
            dbbTrace::OutputString( buf, false );
        } else {
            // Save line
            size_t l = strlen(buf);
            if( i_line >= m_Levels || i_buf + l >= m_Bytes ) {
                // We have saved all of the stack we can save
                break;
            }
            buf[ l - 1 ] = '\0';    // Remove trailing '\n'
            char * s = & m_Buffer[ i_buf ];
            m_Lines[ i_line++ ] = s;
            strncpy( s, buf, l );
            i_buf += l;
        }
    } // while

    return result;
} // MSJExceptionHandler::ImagehlpStackWalk()
```

Comment: this is for current thread. i want to do for different thread