# c++ : convert symbols to code line numbers programmatically

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, demangler

I'm developing under `Linux/gcc`

I currently use the following to get a stack trace on custom thrown exceptions. `Demangled` functions names and `line numbers` are as expected, but I would like to avoid the use of `addr2line` to have a full control on the formatting of the output strings.

```
static void posix_print_stack_trace()
{
    int i, trace_size = 0;
    char **messages = (char **)NULL;

    trace_size = backtrace(stack_traces, MAX_STACK_FRAMES);
    messages = backtrace_symbols(stack_traces, trace_size);

    for (i = 0; i < trace_size; ++i)
    {
        if (addr2line(program_invocation_name, stack_traces[i]) != 0)
        {
            printf("  error determining line # for: %s\n", messages[i]);
        }
    }
    if (messages) { free(messages); }
}

static int addr2line(char const * const program_name, void const * const addr)
{
    char addr2line_cmd[512] = {0}; 
    sprintf(addr2line_cmd,"addr2line -C -f -p -i -e %.256s %p", program_name, addr);
    return system(addr2line_cmd);
}
```

**Note :** The use of `-f` for displaying the functions names in play in the stack trace and `-C` to display them demangled.

**Q :** Does anyone could point me on a programmatic solution ? 
(And if possibly give me some advices on how to get it working as well with `MinGW/gcc`).

NB : Or may be simply using `gdb` in some way could help in getting more customized output ?

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT** : It looks like for the windows part, it is doable that way : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6207030/1715716

**EDIT** : The above points to a Microsoft Visual only solution, so is finally useless to me.

Comment: I also tried to customize `addr2line` which is a single file, but relies on a dependency that I do not have : `libelftc`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably could use or adapt (at least on Linux, and systems using ELF and DWARF) the `libbacktrace` by Ian Taylor, which is currently inside GCC source tree. See [here](https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/blob/master/libbacktrace/); in principle it should be usable independently of GCC (provided you obey its BSD-like license).

Comment: I don't have any problem with the license, since my own program will be shared under a BSD-like one too. Thanks for the pointer. I'll go into it.

Comment: As you said, I was able to build `libbacktrace` independently from gcc (note that this feature is only part of the early gcc 4.8). I haven't tested building it using MinGW. Hope this is doable, since the pointer given in the EDIT part of my question is Visual only stuff (haven't seen that in the first time)...