# With MODULEENTRY32 and MODULEINFO, what are the steps to scan for a specific INT value in a separate process?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have enumerated a processes modules and have a `MODULEINFO`.  From that I have a base address, size of the module, and the entrypoint.  If I have a separate process with an integer `int x = 4` defined in `main()`, can I scan for that integer's address using what I have with `MODULEINFO`?  Wouldn't `x` exist on the stack, which is separate from the module exe?

I tried making a loop with the base address and `SizeOfImage` member, casting the base address to a `byte*`, and then adding 1 byte and then casting it to a `int*` to search for a specific value, however every value I got back was a "0".  I believe my method was (grossly) incorrect.

If it is possible to scan an `int` value can anyone point me in the general direction to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes--local variables (non-static ones, anyway) are allocated on the stack. To see their values, you'll need to write something on the order of a debugger, such as pausing the program while it's running (and the function containing the variable of interest is active), and walk the stack to find the value.

Since you're apparently using Windows, functions you'll probably want to look at include:

- [`WaitForDebugEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681423.aspx) (or [`WaitForDebugEventEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt171594.aspx))
- [`ContinueDebugEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679285.aspx)
- [`Stackwalk64`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dbghelp/nf-dbghelp-stackwalk64)

You'll probably also want to look at the [dbghlp API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dbghelp/), probably starting with these:

- [`SymInitialize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dbghelp/nf-dbghelp-syminitialize)
- [`SymFromName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dbghelp/nf-dbghelp-symfromname)
- [`SymCleanup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dbghelp/nf-dbghelp-symcleanup)

There's a lot more there to consider, but that's probably enough to at least get a bit of a start. I previously posted [an answer that demonstrates StackWalk64, and some of the Sym* stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6207030/179910).

Here's some code with the bare skeleton of a debugger that will spawn a child process, and then log the debug events it produces:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "child_process.h"

void dispatch_child_event(DEBUG_EVENT const &event, child_process const &child) { 
    char *file_name;
    char buffer[512];

    switch ( event.dwDebugEventCode ) {
    case LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT:
        file_name = child.get_string(event.u.LoadDll.lpImageName);
        if ( event.u.LoadDll.fUnicode)
            printf("Loading %S\n", (wchar_t *)file_name);
        else
            printf("Loading %s\n", file_name);            

        break;

    case EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT:
        switch (event.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode) 
        { 
            case EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION: 
            {                
                if ( event.u.Exception.dwFirstChance)
                    break;
                EXCEPTION_RECORD const &r = event.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord;
                printf("Access Violation %x at %0#p\n",
                        r.ExceptionCode,
                        r.ExceptionAddress);
                break;
            }

            case EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT: 
                printf("Breakpoint reached\n");
                break;

            case EXCEPTION_DATATYPE_MISALIGNMENT: 
                if ( !event.u.Exception.dwFirstChance)
                    printf("Misaligned data exception.\n");
                break;

            case EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP: 
                printf("Single Step...\n");
                break;

            case DBG_CONTROL_C: 
                if ( !event.u.Exception.dwFirstChance)
                    printf("Control+C pressed\n");
                break;    
            break;
        }

    case CREATE_THREAD_DEBUG_EVENT:
        printf("Client created a thread\n");
        break;

    case CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT:
        printf("Create-Process\n");
        break;

    case EXIT_THREAD_DEBUG_EVENT:
        printf("Thread exited.\n");
        break;

    case UNLOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT:
        printf("DLL being unloaded\n");
        break;

    case OUTPUT_DEBUG_STRING_EVENT: {
        OUTPUT_DEBUG_STRING_INFO const &d = event.u.DebugString;
        char *string = child.get_debug_string(d.lpDebugStringData,
                                        d.nDebugStringLength);
        if ( d.fUnicode) 
            printf("Debug string: %S\n", string);
        else
            printf("Debug string: %s\n", string);
        break;
    }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    DEBUG_EVENT event;

    if ( argc < 2 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: Trace [executable|PID]");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    child_process child(argv[1]);

    do { 
        WaitForDebugEvent(&event, INFINITE);

        dispatch_child_event(event, child);

        ContinueDebugEvent( event.dwProcessId,
                            event.dwThreadId,
                            DBG_CONTINUE );

    } while ( event.dwDebugEventCode != EXIT_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT);

    return 0;
}
```

That uses the following `child_process` header:

```
#ifndef CHILD_PROCESS_H_INC_
#define CHILD_PROCESS_H_INC_

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <io.h>

#include "syserror.h"

struct no_spawn {
    no_spawn() { system_error("Spawning Program"); }
};

class child_process {
    HANDLE process_;
    HANDLE thread_;

    mutable char buffer[FILENAME_MAX];

public:
    child_process(char const *filename);

    char *get_string(void *string_name, DWORD num = 0) const;
    char *get_debug_string(void *string, DWORD num) const;   

    HANDLE process() { return process_; }
    HANDLE thread() { return thread_; }

    ~child_process() { CloseHandle(process()); }
};

#endif
```

The implementation of that class is as follows:

```
#include "child_process.h"

static BOOL find_image(char const *name, char *buffer) {
    // Try to find an image file named by the user.
    // First search for the exact file name in the current
    // directory.  If that's not found, look for same base name
    // with ".com", ".exe" and ".bat" appended, in that order.
    // If we can't find it in the current directory, repeat
    // the entire process on directories specified in the
    // PATH environment variable.
    //
#define elements(array) (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]))

    static char *extensions[] = {".com", ".exe", ".bat", ".cmd"};
    int i;
    char temp[FILENAME_MAX];

    if (-1 != _access(name, 0)) {
        strcpy(buffer, name);
        return TRUE;
    }

    for (i=0; i<elements(extensions); i++) {
        strcpy(temp, name);
        strcat(temp, extensions[i]);
        if ( -1 != _access(temp, 0)) {
            strcpy(buffer, temp);
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    _searchenv(name, "PATH", buffer);
    if ( buffer[0] != '\0')
        return TRUE;

    for ( i=0; i<elements(extensions); i++) {
        strcpy(temp, name);
        strcat(temp, extensions[i]);
        _searchenv(temp, "PATH", buffer);
        if ( buffer[0] != '\0')
            return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}

child_process::child_process(char const *filename) {
    if (isdigit(filename[0])) {
        DWORD id = atoi(filename);
        process_ = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, atoi(filename));
        DebugActiveProcess(id);
    }
    else {
        char buf[FILENAME_MAX];

        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {0};
        STARTUPINFO si = {0};
        si.cb = sizeof(si);

        if (!find_image(filename, buf))
            throw no_spawn();

        BOOL new_process_ = CreateProcess(buf, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE,
            DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS,
            NULL, NULL,
            &si, &pi);

        if (!new_process_)
            throw no_spawn();

        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        process_ = pi.hProcess;
        thread_ = pi.hThread;
    }
}

char *child_process::get_string(void *string_name, DWORD num) const {
// string_name is a pointer to a pointer to a string, with the pointer and the 
// string itself located in another process_.  We use Readprocess_Memory to read 
// the first pointer, then the string itself into our process_ address space.  
// We then return a pointer (in our address space) to the string we read in.
//
    char *ptr;
    SIZE_T bytes_read;

    if ( 0 == num )
        num = sizeof(buffer);

    if ( string_name == NULL ) 
        return NULL;

    ReadProcessMemory(process_,
        string_name, 
        &ptr, 
        sizeof(ptr),
        &bytes_read);

    if (NULL == ptr ) 
        return NULL;

    ReadProcessMemory(process_,
        ptr,
        buffer,
        num,
        &bytes_read);

    return buffer;
}

char *child_process::get_debug_string(void *string, DWORD num) const {

    static char buffer[FILENAME_MAX];
    SIZE_T bytes_read;

    if ( string == NULL ) 
        return NULL;

    ReadProcessMemory(process_,
        string, 
        buffer, 
        num,
        &bytes_read);
    return buffer;
}
```

That's not enough to do everything you want yet, but at least it should give you a start in the general direction.

Oh, one disclaimer: I wrote most of this code quite a long time ago. There are parts I'd certainly do differently if I were to write it today.

Comment: Thank you!  This may be an entirely other question, but what about searching for the addresses global variables?  I'm guessing they may be located in some module with the Data Segment.   If they are in a module I'm hoping that enumerating the modules and starting from their base addresses may be a clue.

Comment: @JFantastic: I don't have any code handy for that, but yes, you can find initialized globals statically.