# CaptureStackBackTrace and SymGetLineFromAddr64 can't get line info returns error code 487

Tags: c, windows

```
void printStack(void) {
     HANDLE process = GetCurrentProcess();
     SymInitialize( process, NULL, TRUE );

     SymSetOptions(SYMOPT_LOAD_LINES);


     void *stack[64];
     unsigned short frames = CaptureStackBackTrace( 0, 64, stack, NULL );

     SYMBOL_INFO *symbol = (SYMBOL_INFO*) calloc(sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO) + 256 * sizeof(char), 1);
     symbol->MaxNameLen = 255;
     symbol->SizeOfStruct = sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO);

     IMAGEHLP_LINE64 *line = NULL;
     DWORD lastError = 0;
     DWORD displacement;

  
     printf("Backtrace\n");
     for(int i = 0; i < frames; i++) {
         SymFromAddr(process, (DWORD64)(stack[i]), 0, symbol);
         printf("\t %i: %s\n", frames - i - 1, symbol->Name);
         line = (IMAGEHLP_LINE64 *)malloc(sizeof(IMAGEHLP_LINE64));
         line->SizeOfStruct = sizeof(IMAGEHLP_LINE64);
         if (SymGetLineFromAddr64(process, (DWORD64)(stack[i]), &displacement, line)) {
                printf("%s %i\n", line->FileName, line->LineNumber);
         } else {
                printf("failed\n");
         }
        lastError = GetLastError();
        printf("errcode: %i\n", lastError);
        
        free(line);
        line = NULL;
     }

     free(symbol);
}


Backtrace
         5: _printStack
failed
errcode: 487
         4: _main
failed
errcode: 487
         3: __scrt_common_main_seh
failed
errcode: -1073741819
         2: BaseThreadInitThunk
failed
errcode: 487
         1: RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath
failed
errcode: 487
         0: RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath
failed
errcode: 487
```

I am trying to extract line numbers and file names from SymGetLineFromAddr64 but the address I am inputting is invalid.  I am using (DWORD64)(stack[i]) for the address.
What address do I use to be able to extract line information?

Comment: Use the [StackWalk64 function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705650/stackwalk64-on-windows-get-symbol-name).

Comment: You can't rely on the `GetLastError()` result unless the API function failed.

Comment: SymGetLineFromAddr64 failed

Comment: My bad, I was mislead by your reference to `lastError` on the "failed\n" line (before it gets set), but you're not actually printing out the value there.

Comment: Does adding a call to `SymSetOptions(SYMOPT_LOAD_LINES);` after the call to `SymInitialize()` help?

Comment: It does not help.  I just tried it and I get the same result.

Comment: I removed line = NULL and got some results.  It looks to be a memory issue with this function it results in erratic behavior.

Comment: I ran your code in minimal program, it gets filenames and line numbers, I don't get any error until it hits `BaseThreadInitThunk`. Your error handling is wrong. `GetLastError()` should be called immediately after fail. Change `printf("failed\n");` to `lastError = GetLastError(); printf("error %d", lastError);` Also end with `SymCleanup(process)` (but it won't change things in this case)

Comment: I am getting results some of the time but I am getting behavior that would be desribed as a memory issue.  Erratic results.  It might be my computer but I switched to StackWalk64 and the memory issues went away.

Comment: I think it is because I am not using Visual Studio and I needed to add some compile options to the compile command.  I am going to post my own answer soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using cl.exe in my Makefile without the /Zi compile option.  When I added /Zi the line numbers and filenames appeared.